# MongoDB struggling to update DB

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, next.js

I'm new to MongoDB. I have a DB where cards data will be stored and update counts if the user likes the cards. Giving me a total likes number.

I keep getting my res as a 400 and I can't work out why. I got the update method to work manually. but when I put it into a function it does not work.

I'm using NEXT JS API routes.

```
import dbConnect from "../../utils/dbConnect";
import FavSchema from "../../models/FavoriteModel";

dbConnect();

export default async (req, res) => {
  const { method } = req;

  switch (method) {
    case "GET":
      try {
      } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).json({ success: false });
      }
      break;
    case "POST":
      try {
        const query = {
          cardId: req.body.cardHandler,
        };

        await FavSchema.findOneAndUpdate(
          query,
          { $inc: { favCount: 1 } },
          { upsert: true }
        );
        res.send("Succesfully saved.");
      } catch (error) {
        res.send(400, { error: "Error" });
      }
  }
};
```

function

```
 const handleCardFavClick = (id) => {
    const cardHandler = {
      id,
    };
    fetch("/api/favcounter", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(cardHandler),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => console.log(data));
    dispatch(makeFav(cardHandler));
  };
```

Thank you!

Comment: What is error? `catch (error) {
        res.send(400, { error: "Error" });
      }`

Comment: Have you tried printing out the error to see what it says, instead of returning a general status code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing

```
{ id: "<id>" }
```

as body in your API and reading "cardHandler" from req.body, which is "undefined".

In your POST API, replace

```
const query = {
      cardId: req.body.cardHandler,
    }
```

with

```
const query = {
      cardId: req.body.id
    }
```

Comment: Nope I had a go at that and didnt work

Comment: This is also an issue in your code. You are passing {id: "<id>"} in your API and reading "cardHandler" from req.body, which is "undefined".
For now, Try printing the "error" in the catch block. What is it?

Comment: when I add error it just comes back with "400"

Comment: Use console.log(error); in catch block in POST API. Comment here what it says.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'findOneAndUpdate' of undefined

Comment: not sure how it is undefined because I console log  ID when I hit the function and a ID gets passed to it

Comment: Error is not in your function, "FavSchema" is not being imported correctly at the top, make sure you have given the correct path and exported the schema correctly.

Comment: that worked. I cant believe it was that. silly mistake. but its still saying NULL on my db instead of sending the ID

Comment: Are you still using "cardId: req.body.cardHandler," in query? If yes, then replace it with "cardId: req.body.id" as per my answer.